# Springboot Elasticsearch using Spring data - I can't use the respository's own methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, elasticsearch

I am new to implementing elasticsearch, I am trying to implement it in a project, to use the spring data methods, such as save (), findAll (), etc. but apparently, spring boor is not doing the retraction towards the elasticsearch engine.

my pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>es-snapshots</id>
        <name>elasticsearch snapshot repo</name>
        <url>https://snapshots.elastic.co/maven/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>elastic-lucene-snapshots</id>
        <name>Elastic Lucene Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://s3.amazonaws.com/download.elasticsearch.org/lucenesnapshots/83f9835</url>
        <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
        <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
    </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

my entity

```java
import lombok.Data;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;

@Document(indexName = "persona")
@Data
public class Persona {

    @Id
    public int id;

    public String nombre;

    public String apellido;
}
```

my config class

```java
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.ClientConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.RestClients;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchOperations;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.config.EnableElasticsearchRepositories;

@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.demo.elasticRepository")
public class RestClientConfig {

    @Bean
    public RestHighLevelClient client() {
        ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration
                = ClientConfiguration.builder()
                .connectedTo("localhost:9200")
                .build();

        return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
    }

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() {
        return new ElasticsearchRestTemplate(client());
    }
}
```

my controller

```java
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/persona")
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class PersonaController {

    final PersonaElasticRepository personaElasticRepository;
    final ElasticsearchRestTemplate elasticsearchRestTemplate;

    @PostMapping()
    @ResponseBody()
    public ResponseEntity<String> crear(@RequestBody PersonaDTO requestDTO)
    {
        Persona persona = new Persona();
        persona.nombre=requestDTO.getNombre();
        persona.apellido=requestDTO.getApellido();

        personaElasticRepository.save(persona);
        return new ResponseEntity(JsonResponse.success("Viaje creado con éxito", persona, Views.PersonaListar.class), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
    @GetMapping( produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody()
    public ResponseEntity<String> listar()
    {
        List<Persona> persona = new ArrayList<>();
        persona=personaElasticRepository.findAll();
        return new ResponseEntity(JsonResponse.success("Viaje creado con éxito", persona, Views.PersonaListar.class), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

my repository

```java
import com.example.demo.entity.Persona;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository;

import java.util.List;

public interface PersonaElasticRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Persona,Integer> {

    List<Persona> findAll();
}
```

the problem comes when I try to make a call through postman, towards my application it throws this error by console

```
Suppressed: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [PUT], host [http://localhost:9200], URI [/persona/_doc/0?timeout=1m], status line [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request]
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"invalid_type_name_exception","reason":"Document mapping type name can't start with '_', found: [_doc]"}],"type":"invalid_type_name_exception","reason":"Document mapping type name can't start with '_', found: [_doc]"},"status":400}
```

sorry for my english but this is a translation

Comment: can you post the request(url, body etc) that you are using on postman?

Comment: curl --location --request POST 'localhost:8080/persona' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "id":1,
    "nombre":"alan",
    "apellido":"lazo" 
    
}
this is the curl of request

Comment: It is most likely due to version mismatch between your elasticsearch app and the dependencies you are using. Do you know the elasticsearch version that you are using? Spring Boot 2.3.5 works well with ES 7.6.*

Comment: Also, since you are using `spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch`, you don't need to separately define `elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client` and `elasticsearch` dependencies. Also, i noticed you are using v7.4 while sprng boot 2.3.5 is compatible with 7.6. You can simply delete these two dependencies.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I removed both dependencies and now the error changed to `Elasticsearch exception [type = invalid_type_name_exception, reason = Document mapping type name can't start with '_', found: [_doc]]`

I guess it is an error with the entity class and the document tag

Comment: Which version of elasticsearch client you are using?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#preface.versions Look at this for compatibility

Comment: `{
  "name" : "F1TLE_5",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "2p5yCN96RpC6fkh6I9sZtw",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.5.0",
    "build_hash" : "260387d",
    "build_date" : "2017-06-30T23:16:05.735Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.6.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
`
you were right maybe the problem was the version

Comment: Yes. It looks you are using elasticsearch client 5.5.0. that's super old. 7.6 and higher should work fine

Comment: Thank you very much friend for your help, it was indeed a version problem, I really thank you